# EvoSuite failing to connect to server

Tags: evosuite

I followed the exact steps of the evosuite official tutorial (*http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/tutorial-part-1/*), and what I always get is this:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjdbc.png)

It always says that "failed to register client service", then java exceptions were thrown due to connection failure. My device is perfectly connected to the internet. I tried to ping the connection site and there was reply. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer then it worked.